# How to "run" asp.net mvc web app on server 2012 r2

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Ok, so I have made an asp.net/c# mvc Entity based web application in Visual Studio 2013. It works great on my local machine on IIS because of course Visual Studio compiles it for the browser to interpret.  However, now I want to deploy it onto a server on the network here at work so that everyone can start connecting to it and use it.

The server is running MS Server 2012 R2 and is set up as an app server.  I am able to publish the application to the server onto its /sites/Default Web Site site.  However,as is expected, when I then try to navigate to that URL on a client machine, it gives me an error because the files are all .cshtml and .cs and not .html.

I do have some .jpg files in my project and if I add them to the "default documents" section they display just fine so I know that the problem is that the files are not in a browser-friendly format.  I figure I need something on the server to compile and render the pages in the correct format for when a machine connects to the site and tries to view them in the browser.  My question is, how do I get the app to display in the browser when hosted on the server in the same way it would display when compiled through Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Google "deploy asp.net mvc website to iis"

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the problem i think you are new in ASP.NET MVC. At first and most important ASP.NET MVC uses routes to find and create the return html to the client. So basically you do not directly request the .cshtml files because they need to be processed. To deploy the application, you may find several ways

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment

In this link you can find all the deployment step you need to make the application working in Windows Server.